# Facebook SDK 4.0.0 fails to compile with gradle

Tags: java, android, facebook

I setup a new project in Android to test Facebook (they way overly complicated SDK) anyhow I'm having the following problems.

My project compiles fine and works on my devices without Facebook SDK included, but when adding the sdk with the official instruction it fails to compile.

I'm using java version "1.8.0_05".

the gradle setup is:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Facebook ads a whole load of methods of which if you include Facebook SDK and Google play services you hit the method limit for Android (64k..)

So to fix this, simply add such to Gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

Then in you're Android gradle.build

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        //And others
}
```

If you still have problems (although the above worked for me) you can try to add:

```
class MyAndroidApplication extends MultiDexApplication
```